# Nested preferenceScreen store its preference into the different shared preferences files

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am now creating a PreferenceFragment with nested PreferenceScreen.

The preferences_layout.xml looks like below

```
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:title="@string/preference_setting_title" >

            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="@string/pref_key_switch"
                android:title="@string/title__preference"
                android:summary="@string/summary_title_preference"
                android:defaultValue="true" />

            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="@string/pref_key_auto_enable"
                android:title="@string/title_auto_enable_preference"
                android:summary="@string/summary_auto_enable_preference"
                android:dependency="@string/pref_key_switch"
                android:defaultValue="true" />

            <PreferenceScreen
                android:key="@string/pref_key_enabled_items"
                android:title="@string/title_enabled_items"
                android:summary="@string/summary_enabled_items"
                android:dependency="@string/pref_key_switch" >
            </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The nested PreferenceScreen perference items will be dynamically added on that PreferenceScreen onClick. 
Due to need to check the items already exist before adding a new one, so i use the following ways to check:

```
int count = enabledPreferenceScreen.getPreferenceCount();
for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i) {
//Do the check with new one
}
```

All works ok. But the problem is that when this setting activity is destroyed and relaunch again, enabledPreferenceScreen.getPreferenceCount() will become 0. 
So i check with the app/shared_prefs/xxxx.xml, the values are saved, but the problem is that there is no nested screen hierarchy information in that store value xml.

How to solve this issue?  Rebuild the PreferenceScreen from the preference_layout.xml cannot rebuild the daynamic add items preferences.

Is it possible to save the nested PreferenceScreen data into another /shared_prefs/xxx2.xml? How to achieve it?

Thanks a lot.